# Using memcpy in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy

I am little confused on the parameters for the [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) function. If I have

```
int* arr = new int[5];

int* newarr = new int[6];
```

and I want to copy the elements in `arr` into `newarr` using `memcopy`,

```
memcpy(parameter, parameter, parameter)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What documentation do you have for memcpy?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So the order is `memcpy(destination, source, number_of_bytes)`.

Therefore, you can place the old data at the beginning of `newarr` with

```
memcpy(newarr, arr, 5 * sizeof *arr);
/* sizeof *arr == sizeof arr[0]  == sizeof (int) */
```

or at the end with

```
memcpy(newarr+1, arr, 5 * sizeof *arr);
```

Because you know the data type of `arr` and `newarr`, pointer arithmetic works.  But inside `memcpy` it doesn't know the type, so it needs to know the number of bytes.

Another alternative is `std::copy` or `std::copy_n`.

```
std::copy_n(arr, 5, newarr);
```

For fundamental types like `int`, the bitwise copy done by `memcpy` will work fine.  For actual class instances, you need to use `std::copy` (or `copy_n`) so that the class's customized assignment operator will be used.

Comment: @refp: Adding a comment was fine, but there was no need to complicate the code.

Comment: sure the parentheses in conjunction with `sizeof` might have been a stylistic modification to your post, but I sure wouldn't consider it to be a method of making it more complicated. consistancy is key in programming (especially when dealing with novices, easier (for them) to just deal with one "form" of `sizeof` (excuse my weird wording)).

Comment: But there are two separate forms of `sizeof`

Comment: of course, and our mutual edited comment now make that clear, I guess I don't mind the middle ground. now it's time (04:46am CET) to get some sleep.

Answer (score -1):

```
memcpy(dest,src,size)
dest -to which variable 
src - from which variable
size - size of src varible

int* arr = new int[5];    //source
int* newarr = new int[6];  // destination

for(int i = 0;i<5;i++) {arr[i] = i * 3;printf("  %d  ",arr[i]);}
memcpy(newarr,arr,sizeof(int)* 5);
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++) printf("%d",newarr[i]);
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.