# How do I copy arrays that contain non primitive types?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing C++ on an Arduino. I've run into a problem trying to copy and array using `memcpy`.

```
Character characters[5] = {
    Character("Bob", 40, 20),
    Character("Joe", 30, 10),
    ...
};
```

I then pass this array into a constructor like so:

```
Scene scene = Scene(characters, sizeof(characters)/sizeof(Character));
```

Inside this constructor I attempt to copy the characters using memcpy:

```
memcpy(this->characters, characters, characters_sz);
```

This seems to lock up my application. Upon research it appears that memcpy is not the right tool for this job. If I comment that line out the rest of the application continues to freeze.

I can't use vectors because they're not supported on the Arduino, neither is `std::copy`. Debugging is a pain.

Is there any way to do this?

### **Edit**

The reason why I am copying is because multiple objects will get their own copy of the characters. Each class can modify and destroy them accordingly because their copies. I don't want to have the `Scene` class responsible for creating the characters, so I'd rather pass them in.

Comment: Is `Character` trivially copyable?

Comment: You are not using Array<T>.

Comment: `memcpy()` is a C library function that knows absolutely nothing about C++ classes.

Comment: `std::copy()` will do the job. It will probably even decay to `std::memcpy()` for POD types.

Comment: Why all the hate for someone who's just got involved in C++? What does any of the irrelevant comments have to do with helping someone? I asked because I'm trying to improve my open source [MIDI controller](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C4fSJExXUAI1lTs.jpg:large).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think `Arduino` was a rather important tag here (restrictions on the language for example).

Comment: @Danny No, I don't think it's actually relevant. The restriction about using `std::vector` is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @A.S.H I wasn't even aware there was `std::array` on the Arduino. By `array<T>` I mean "Array that contains non primitive types".

Comment: @BugHunterUK _"Why all the hate ..."_ What hate??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ regarding your stupid comment on "upon research". I got the information from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439715/using-memcpy-in-c ... "For fundamental types like int, the bitwise copy done by memcpy will work fine. For actual class instances, you need to use std::copy (or copy_n) so that the class's customized assignment operator will be used.". What were you trying to get at exactly?

Comment: @BugHunterUK Well, `std::copy()` sounds fine, why are you bothering to use it?

Comment: @BugHunterUK that's fine, I think you should edit the title because what you are using is called a *"C-style array"* :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ erm ... because `std::copy()` is not available on the Arduino. I already researched that ... something you seem to assume I hadn't done.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to copy the members individually, or create a copy constructor in the `Character` class / struct

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what's going on in your code.

- First of all, you aren't using `std::array` as your question title suggests,  you are using a built-in array.
  You could concievably use `std::array` instead, and just use copy constructor of `std::array`. But that brings us to second question.
- When you are doing `memcpy` in the constructor of `Scene`, what is the actual size of `this->characters`? It's not a good thing to have a constructor that takes `characters_sz` dynamically if in fact there is a static limit on how many it can accept.

If I were you and really trying to avoid dynamic allocations and `std::vector`, I would use `std::array` for both things, the member of `Scene` and the temporary variable you are passing, and I would make the constructor a template, so that it can accept arbitrary sized `std::array` of characters. But, I would put a static assert so that if the size of the passed array is too large, it fails at compile time.

Also assuming you are in C++11 here.

---

I guess depending on your application, this strategy wouldn't be appropriate. It might be that the size of the arrays really needs to be variable at run-time, but you still don't want to make dynamic allocations. In that case you could have a look at `boost::static_vector`.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html

`boost::static_vector` will basically be like a heap-allocated buffer large enough to hold N objects, but it won't default construct N of them for sure, you may have only one or two etc. It will keep track of how many of them are actually alive, and basically act like a stack-allocated `std::vector` with a capacity limit of `N`.

Comment: _"Also assuming you are in C++11 here, if you aren't, I am truly sorry for your [loss]."_ Well that's kind of a silly thing to say.

Comment: Yeah, mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::copy_n`:

```
std::copy_n(characters, num_characters, this->characters);
```

Note that the order of arguments is different from `memcpy` and the number is the number of elements, not the size of those elements.  You'll also need `#include <algorithm>` in the top of your source file.

That said, you're probably better off using a `std::vector` rather than a fixed size array,  That way you can just use a simple assignment to copy it, and you can grow and shrink it dynamically.